# Curl call to aspx

Tags: asp.net, curl

I have a website that is login and password protected, and, there is a "Log In" button there. I can curl the Login.aspx that amongst a lot of code returns the following:

```
<input name="UserSX" type="text" id="UserSX" class="finput" />
<input name="PasswordSX" type="password" id="PasswordSX" class="finput" />
<input type="submit" name="SubmitBtn" value="Log In" id="SubmitBtn" />
```

What I am trying to do is to execute a curl call that would pass my login and password so I could access other aspx sub-sites via command line in shell in Linux. So far I tried:

```
DATA="UserSX='myusername'&PasswordSX='mypassword'"
curl -d $DATA https://mysebsite.com/app/Login.aspx
```

but as a result I receive the same login site.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share more information? Seems to be fine but I'm not sure what's the strategy in the code behind when you post that data. If you're not using a multipart form it looks ok

Comment: The issue is that when I login using a browser I'm getting redirected to another site meanwhile curl just displays the same login site. I do not know mechanism used on the server side, all I know is that's aspx

Comment: The redirection occurs at a different level, that's why. When you're redirected the browser gets the response and process it for you following that redirection. CURL just executes your request and responds with a 302 (Redirect). Use -v to see what's behind the curtains (verbose), you can see the server telling you HTTP/1.1 302 found or 301 (Moved). In a Linux environment using curl manually tries to use -L to follow any redirect automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use -L to follow a redirect. In case it doesn't work use -v (verbose) to see what's going on in the server side. We don't see the code here so it's not clear enough how the redirection is happening.